# How can I set a bottom position on a horizontally scrollbar in Ag Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to position the horizontally scrollbar on a bottom position when some field of the table is changed.I tried with : [Scrolling Ag Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#scrolling) using ensureIndexVisible()
But as least I know it is only for vertical scrollbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a method `ensureColumnVisible(colId)`, from docs (in the same section you are refering to):

> Ensures the column is visible, scrolling the table if needed.